# nuxtjs, How to put /_nuxt/ in a subdirectory and BUILD

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a question on nuxtjs build.

Is there any way to satisfy the following conditions?

The dist directory is the document root. (`xxxx.com/` = `dist/` directory)
The actual content is placed under `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/`.
I want to build `/_nuxt/` directory to `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/` under the above conditions.

All accesses other than `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/` will be redirected to `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/` (already implemented with nuxtjs redirects)

I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: Good luck to someone who try to understand you.

Comment: @Mises
Please let me know if my question is not clear. I am not a native English speaker.

If the intent is difficult to understand, the client has requested it:(

Comment: For now, setting build.publicPath without setting router.base in nuxt.config seems to work (although the static directory must be created with the structure /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ from the beginning)....

Comment: Now it makes sense if you want static file directory. Edit your question "How to build Nuxt.js app with static files, so people can download them" 拍手

Answer (score 0):

To serve static file on **Nuxt 3** app, you just need to place them in `public` folder in **Nuxt.js** its `static` folder. To make subdirectories, just create folders, where the folder name is the subdirectory name. Example `/images/cute_cat.jpg` `/documents/salaries/cute_document.pdf`